# Why doesn't  function "qsort" in the standard library work in my code?

Tags: c, qsort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000
struct island{  double left;           //gobal
                double right;
                } island[MAX];
...

int cmp(const void *ptr1,const void *ptr2 )           
{
    return (*(struct island*)ptr1).right >  (*(struct island*)ptr2).right;
}

qsort(island,num,sizeof(island[0]),cmp);    // "num" is the number of the input data

 //when I do print,it seems that if num<10 is right,else wrong
for(i=0;i<num;i++)          
    {
        printf("%g\t",island[i].right);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cmp` function is supposed to return

- `1` or greater if the left value is `>` the right value
- `0` if the values are equal
- `-1` or less if the left value is `<` the right value

Your comparison only returns `1` (for the `>` case) or `0` (all other cases).

Answer (score 1):

Your `cmp` function is returning `1` if the left item is greater than the right item, otherwise it's returning `0`. The documentation for `qsort` states:

> ```
>  The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to,  or
>    greater  than  zero  if  the first argument is considered to be respec‐
>    tively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
> ```

Try this for your compare function:

```
int cmp(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)           
{
    double first = (*(struct island *)ptr1).right;
    double second = (*(struct island *)ptr2).right;
    if (first < second) return -1;
    else if (first > second) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `cmp()` function should return -1, 0 or 1 (or any negative/0/any positive)to represent ordering of the given objects.  your function returns 0 or 1.

try with:

```
int cmp(const void *ptr1,const void *ptr2 )           
{
    return (*(struct island*)ptr2).right - (*(struct island*)ptr1).right;
}
```

Comment: I believe this will be problematic when the difference between the double values exceeds the maximum value of an int (which is very likely given the range of doubles.

Comment: "Comparison by subtraction" is always a bug, except for a few rare cases.

Comment: This will always return zero. Can you see why? :-)

Comment: @Matt, Andrey: right, this is just a sample to show the intent.  maybe `strcmp()` would be a better example.

Answer (score 0):

From the qsort man page:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to,  or
> greater  than  zero  if  the first argument is considered to be respec‐
> tively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.  If two members
> compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

It looks to me like your cmp doesn't do that.